# loop for post to be displayed according to pagination page number

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am making a pagination system for wordpress posts to be displayed in order of 8 post per page leaving out the the very first result in every page. For that I made this code

```
<?php $offset_wordp=mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']); ?>
    <? query_posts ('cat=-103&posts_per_page=8&offset='.$offset_wordp.'') ?>

 <? while (have_posts ()) { the_post ();  ?>

    <div class="reu-sec">

        <h2><a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"><? the_title (); ?><span class="sbttlmn">&nbsp<?= get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'sub-title', true); ?></span></a></h2>

       <div style="clear: both"></div>

    </div>

    <? } ?>
</div>
```

In the above code I am using `offset` in order to filter results after that number of posts. The thing I was trying is to get the `page number` and then filter offset accordingly, eg. if page number is 1, then the `offset=1`, if page number is 2, then offset is 8 and so on. So that post is auto filtered according to page number.

Comment: Have you seen this post? The same questions on wordpress.stackexchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50494/wordpress-category-loop-offset-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset for the first page will be 0. From second page onwards, offset will increase by 8 use the following formula to calculate the offset.

```
$offset = ($page_num == 1)? 1 : ($page_num - 1) * 8;
```

Comment: but i want that the very first result should be removed and using this it shows the result

Comment: Edited the answer. Now, if the page number is 1, the offset is 1. Else the offset is calculated based on the page number.